# Valor de ruta en Html.ActionLink no reconoce

Tags: javascript

Buenas tengo mi función Buscar en donde se carga el contenido de mi tabla sin problemas, pero en el html.ActionLink que lo puse en una cadena de caracteres javascript no me reconoce el valor de ruta, me genera un error en data[i].idEntidad, me dice que data no existe en el contexto actual y tampoco me reconoce el icono que trato de poner. Espero me puedan ayudar o tratar de mejorar el codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
function Buscar() {
            var dni = document.getElementById("dni").value;
            var contenido = "";
            var tbody = document.getElementById("tbDatos");
            $.get("Paciente/listarPacientes/?dniPaciente=" + dni, function (data) {
                if (data == "") {
                    error("DNI incorrecto o usuario no registrado");
                } else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        contenido += "<tr>";
                        contenido += "<td hidden>" + data[i].idEntidad + "</td>";
                        contenido += "<td>" + data[i].dni + "</td>";
                        contenido += "<td>" + data[i].nombre + "</td>";
                        contenido += "<td>" + data[i].sexo + "</td>";
                        contenido += `<td align="center">
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit","editarHC","HC", new { id= data[i].idEntidad }, new {@class= "fas fa-user fa-2x" })

                                        <i class="fas fa-book-medical fa-2x" style="color:#99B9F9"
                                        aria-hidden="true" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addConsulta" onclick="Abrir(${data[i].idEntidad})">
                                        </i>

                                    </td> `
                        contenido += "</tr>";
                    }
                    tbody.innerHTML = contenido;
                }
            })
        }
```

---

Para responder la pregunta de @Alfabravo, el error es que no reconoce el valor de ruta, lo ponga en foto para que puedan verlo mejor[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tambien realice el cambio que propuso Eduardo Jaramillo Licea pero me bota el error de que no reconoce el Html.ActionLink. Siempre me dice que el valor no existe en el contexto actual[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Procura poner el error exacto, no un resumen del error. Puedes estar omitiendo detalles clave para resolver tu duda

Comment: Es posible que el error sea, que en tu evento  intentas tomar un parámetro `data[i].idEntidad`, que no existe por que lo agregas como texto, en este caso agrégalo así. `new { id=  ${data[i].idEntidad }}`, para que se concatene el valor y no todo como texto.

Comment: Si le agrege el simbolo $ y data[i].idEntidad entre corchetes, pero no se concatena el valor, me muestra error en data y en idEntidad diciendo que no existe en el contexto actual